# Rails: button_tag vs regular %button on HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I found out that there are 2 ways to create buttons on Ruby on Rails. We are using HAML for our templating.

**First way:**

```
= button_tag 'Submit', type: 'submit', class: 'btn btn-primary primary-button'
```

**Second way:**

```
%button.btn.btn-primary.primary-button{ type: 'submit' } Submit
```

Both ways converts it to HTML.

What should I choose? Are there any pros/cons of using either/or? Is it just matter of preference?

Answer (score 2):

You can choose any way. There are no pros and cons. It's like exiting `irb` console: you can type either `exit` or `quit`, you'll exit anyway. Just a matter of preference.

As for me, I prefer to use the second way when the element class is static:

```
%button.btn.btn-primary.primary-button{ type: 'submit' } Submit
```

and the first way when it's calculated dynamically:

```
= button_tag 'Submit', type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary #{extra_class}"
```

(Of course, if you'll have your own helper method `button_tag` there will be a difference. But I don't think you will need to redefine built-in helpers.)

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you need. If you are using the helper just to render a basic HTML button tag, then it might be even faster to just use an HTML tag, not even HAML needed. I guess it comes to the context where something might have pros and cons.

```
%button.btn.btn-primary.primary-button{ type: 'submit' } Submit
<button class="btn btn-primary primary-button" type="subimt">Submit</button>
```

It will be faster since rails doesn't even have to turn your HAML code to HTML.

---

BUT, the button_tag helper will be used inside a form that's already a form_for/tag/with helper, surrounded by other text_field/text_field_tag, text_area/text_area_tag, etc, helpers, and it makes more sense to just use the button_tag helper for consistency.

You could ask the same question about %input{type: "text"} against text_field_tag, but it's easier to decide to use the helpers since it handles really easy the names of the fields to work with rails out of the box: you can have prefixes, suffixes, it handles arrays, etc and for complex and nested forms it can be a pain in the ass. Using just HAML will mean you have to set the names manually, so you'll want the helpers to develop your forms faster.

Also, the helpers has more options that the common html attributes that plays well with rails-ujs: confirm, disable_with, remote, etc. You can, of course, replicate the same data attributes created by those options, but the consistency with other helpers will be a pro if you already use them, you won't have to remember if the remote: true option is write `data: {remote: true}` or anything else.

Personally, I always use rails form helpers because I will use them for forms and inputs so feels natural to also use the submit_tag, button_tag, etc helpers even knowing they are pretty easy to write with HAML too.

And for the last pro I can think, you could have your own button_tag helper. If you want all your buttons to be of class "btn btn-primary" you can just override the button_tag helper and you won't need to change any view.

---

As a con, of course you have speed, using the helper adds an extra step with extra logic. I don't think it will be a real real problem since it's not really a heavy logic, and if you reeeeally wan't to squeeze every milisecond you might even want to just write pure html then and not even HAML.

You have also the con of the learning curve. Everybody knows HTML and the change to HTML to HAML is straightforward most of the times. Translating the HTML tag to the helper tag options requires you to read the docs of the helper, it has some caveats (f.button of button_tag? etc). I also don't think it's a really big issue, everything has a learning curve and I think the pros are worth it.